# Function template which returns a function parameter inside an array

Tags: c++, arrays, function, templates

I'm trying to create a function template which returns the given parameter contained within an array of its own type:

```
template<typename T>
auto encArr(T obj){T arr[1] = {obj};} // For instance - if obj is an integer it should return
                                      // int arr[1] = {obj};
                                      // In general, it should return
                                      // T arr[1] = {obj};
```

But when I try to use the function my compiler fights back:

```
int test = 10;
int test[1] = encArr(huh);            // error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer
```

Perhaps I'm just going about this in the wrong way. It is quite important however that I'm not using a std::vector<>, I would like to use a standard C++ array. Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: You can't. Things you can do: use `std::array<int, 1>`, use `[&test, &test + 1)` like an array with one element, use the array initializer directly and skip the function.

Answer (score 3):

First off, your example is missing a `return` statement.

But, in any case, you simply can't `return` a C-style flat array.  But you can return a C++-style `std::array` instead, if you don't want to use `std::vector`.

```cpp
#include <array>

template<typename T>
auto encArr(const T &obj){
    return std::array<T, 1>{obj};
}
```

```cpp
auto test = encArr(10);
// use test[0] as needed...
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/Syty5R)

Comment: I concur with this solution. Arrays defined in "C" style so int A[10]; cannot be returned by functions. Since C++11 there are std::array (fixed length) and std::vector (changing length at runtime). They can be returned, the can be passed by value or reference and IMO makes code more stable, predictable and readable. I think one of the issues is that people still are being taught C++ as it was in 98.